# Deleting a record from a file in c++

Tags: c++

I have wriiten a code to add , delete and dispaly a record of employees consisting of employee ID ,name,age and location.
But I am unable to code the delete function

My code is as follows:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


class Document
{

public: 
int Add();
void Delete();
void Display();
int No_of_lines();
int empno();

private:
fstream document;
fstream newdocument;
string data;
int age;
int emp_id;
int idtodelete;
char name[100],loc[100];

};

int Document::No_of_lines()
{
int number = 0;
document.open("document.txt");
while (getline(document, data))
{
    ++number;
}
return number;
}


int Document::Add()
{
        Document d1;
        document.open ( "document.txt",ios::app);
        int x = d1.No_of_lines();
        int emp_id = ++x;
        cout << "The employee ID is: " << emp_id;
        document <<emp_id;
        cout<< "\n Ënter Name:" ;
        cin>>name;
        document <<"\t Name:"<< name;
        cout<<"Enter Age:";
        cin>> age;
        document << "\t Age:"<< age;
        cout<< "Enter location:";
        cin>> loc;
        document << "\t Location:"<< loc;
        document << "\n";
        document.close();           
        return 0;
}

void Document::Delete()
{
Document d2;
d2.Display();
int num;
char line[1000];
document.open("document.txt");
newdocument.open("newdocument.txt");
cout << "Enter the ID to delete \n";
cin >> idtodelete;
while (document.good())
{
    const int maxchar = 1000;
    const int maxtokens = 10;
    char* token[maxtokens] = {};
    char split[maxchar];
    document.getline(split, maxchar);
    int n = 0;
    token[0] = strtok(split, " ");
    istringstream(token[0]) >> num;
    if (num != idtodelete)
         {
             document >> emp_id >> name >> age >> loc;
             newdocument << emp_id<< name<< age<< loc;
         }
    else
    {
    }
}
    document.close();
    newdocument.close();
    remove("document.txt");
    rename("newdocument.txt", "document.txt");
}


void Document::Display()
{

        document.open("document.txt");

        while (!document.eof())
        {
            getline(document,data);
            cout<<data<<endl;
        }

        document.close();
}


int main()
{
Document d;
char ans;
int ch;

do
{
system ( "cls");
cout<< "Enter your choice \n";
cout << "\t1. Add Data \n " << "\t2. Delete Data \n" << "\t3. Display Data   \n";
cout<<  "\t4. Exit\n";
cout<< " Enter Choice \n ";
cin >> ch;

switch(ch)
{
    case 1:

        cout << " Adding Data : \n";
        d.Add();
        break;

    case 2:
        //cout << "Deleting data : \n"; 
        d.Delete();
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << "Displaying data : \n";
        d.Display();
        break;

    case 4:
        cout << "Exit";
        break;

    default :
        cout << "Invalid Input \n";
        break;
}
cout<< " click y to quit or any other key to continue " ;
cin>>ans;
}
while (ans != 'y');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The easy way is to open the file, read in all of the employees, and then write out all of the employees except the one you need to delete.

Comment: you don't really have to do this do you ? you'll find thousands of programs doing just that. If you are learning, then you are missing a component: a collection. If you want to link with file, this is serialization. You could use a bit of de-coupling by applying a clean MVC pattern. (I mean don't store streams). And `no_of_lines` is a document wide query, not record-specific. For serialization take a look at `boost::serialization`.

Comment: Ten bucks says this is a homework assignment and boost might as well be on another planet, but @v.oddou is right. At the very least you have two concepts in play here, document and employees. Two concepts generally means two classes. `class Employee` contains the statistics for one and only one employee. `class Document` contains a list of employees (std::vector if allowed by the assignment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way is to remove by employee ID. You just ask for the employee ID, to know what employee to remove.

Then, you cannot remove lines in the middle of a sequential file, so you just

- rename the file as `document.back`
- create a new `document.txt`
- read `document.back` and copy all employees to `document.txt` except the one you want to delete
- close both files
- remove `document.back`

That's all ... except for the usual test for IO errors, backup file existing, and so on...

I tested your code. First, you forgot to close document in method `int Document::No_of_lines()`. Next on my MSVC2008, I have to explicitely call `document.clear()` after reaching end of file. You also do not test `document` immediately after a `getline`, meaning that you execute the code after a bad read.

I removed `newdocument` from `Document` class, because IMHO it is useless. Here is a possible implementation of `Delete`:

```
void Document::Delete()
{
    Document d2;
    Display();
    int num;
    document.open("document.txt");
    document.clear();
    d2.document.open("newdocument.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
    cout << "Enter the ID to delete \n";
    cin >> idtodelete;
    while (document.good())
    {
        getline(document, data);
        if (document) {
            int n = 0;
            istringstream(data) >> num;
            if (num != idtodelete)
            {
                d2.document << data << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    document.close();
    d2.document.close();
    remove("document.txt");
    rename("newdocument.txt", "document.txt");
}
```

Comment: I understood your concept...i have tried somewhat similar concept...edited the delete portion..if you could just go through it..its still not working...can u give a code as per your concept..

Comment: Thanks @Serge Ballesta ... it worked... i was probably unnecesarily wasting tym on parsing the string....Thanks a lot....